# Shopify page metafield of the list type only returning 50 items

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I've got a metafield assigned to pages in my theme and it's the File (List) type. There are 84 items in that list, but Shopify is only returning 50. I figure there is some sort of default limit, but can't find any documentation on how to return all items or at least paginate through them.

A simple version of the Liquid I'm using in the template that returns 50 of the 84 items is

```
{% assign file = page.metafields.custom.collection_images.value %}

{% for field in file %}
    <p>
      {{ field }}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

If I try and count the items in the list using `{{file.count}}`, it actually returns the count as 84, like so

```
{% assign file = page.metafields.custom.collection_images.value %}

<p>{{ file.count }}</p>

{% for field in file %}
    <p>
      {{ field }}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to get all 84 items to render in the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

That a look at using the **paginate** aspect of resources. Any time you wrap a resource with a default of 50 items in **paginate** you should be able to uncork the pages of items that are not returned by default. If it does not work for metafields, then try a different technique I guess. For example to store 84 things in a list, you can use JSON as a replacement? Not ideal but might work, as it all depends on your use case for the list.